# ORDER BY before WHERE - alternatives?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a PostgreSQL database (12.8).

Given `events` sorted by `start_time`, I would like to retrieve the next `10` events after the event with `id = 10`.

My first idea was something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM events
ORDER BY start_time
WHERE id > 10
LIMIT 10;
```

However, this does not work because the `WHERE`-clause is always applied before the `ORDER BY`-clause. In other words, first all events are selected which have an `id > 10`, and only the remaining events are then ordered by `start_time`.

Next, I came up with a CTE expression. If the record with ID `10` has `row_number` `3`:

```sql
WITH ordered_events AS (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_time DESC) AS row_number
  FROM events
)
SELECT *
FROM ordered_events
WHERE row_number > 3
LIMIT 10;
```

This works as desired, if I would know the `row_number` beforehand. However, I only know the ID, i.e. `id = 10`.

**a)** Ideally, I would do something like this (however, I don't know if there is any way to write such an expression):

```sql
WITH ordered_events AS (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_time DESC) AS row_number
  FROM events
)
SELECT *
FROM ordered_events
WHERE row_number > (row_number of row where the ID is 10) # <------
LIMIT 10;
```

**b)** The only alternative I came up with is to first retrieve the `row_number` for *all records* and then make a second query.

First query:

```sql
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_time DESC) AS row_number
FROM events;
```

Now I know that the `row_number` for the record with ID `10` is `3`. Thus, I have enough information to make the query with the CTE expression as described above. However, the performance is bad because I need to retrieve all records from `events` in the first query.

I would really appreciate it, if you could help me to figure out a (performant) way of doing this.

Comment: "...because the WHERE-clause is always applied before the ORDER BY-clause..." -- not true. Database engines execute the query using internal strategies. That ordering you are talking about is probably taught as a pedagogical tools, but real work engines don't work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only want rows with a start time less than ID 10's start time. Use a `WHERE` clause for this.

```
select *
from events where start_time < (select start_time from events where id = 10)
order by start_time desc
limit 10;
```

This query may benefit from an index on start_time. (I take it for granted that there already is an index on ID to find the row with ID 10 quickly.)